# desktop switching in windows (virtual desktops)

Tags: windows-7, desktop, virtual-desktop

I would like to know whether it is possible to set up the windows 7 desktop to display multiple virtual desktops, like in Ubuntu where you can switch from one desktop to another using crl+alt+left/up/down/right arrow.

I need this functionality implemented because my windows desktop is always too cluttered.

If anyone is aware of any software to obtain this result please let me know. Basically I need the effect of having two monitors with a single monitor displaying both, just one at a time, and switch between the musing keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Try http://www.lockergnome.com/windows/2012/02/28/how-to-create-multiple-virtual-desktops-in-windows-7-for-free/

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily and comfortably done with [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/):

> VirtuaWin is a virtual desktop manager for the Windows operating system (Win9x/ME/NT/Win2K/XP/Win2003/Vista/Win7). A virtual desktop manager lets you organize applications over several virtual desktops (also called ‘workspaces’).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Dexpot` or `VirtuaWin` !

personally I like Dexpot, it has many advanced features.

Comment: Read [this post](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/47225), you must.